# undefined method filename= for action mailer attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

When trying to execute

```
attachment report[1] do |a|
      a.body = File.read(report[0])
      a.filename = report[0].gsub(/.*\//,'')
    end
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `filename=' for #<Mail::Part:0x929b3b0>
```

report[1] = application/vnd.ms-excel
report[0] = path to my file

Trying another way with a simple text-file fails also

```
@file_name = 'test.txt'
    create_attachment
    attachment :content_type => "text/plain",
      :filename => "Some useless attachment",
      :body => File.read(@file_name)
```

create_attachment just creates the test.txt file. In this case the mail is sent with the attachment but the sent txt-file is empty.

Comment: when setting both :body and :content it works for the text file but not for the excel file     
attachment :content_type => "text/plain",
      :filename => "Some useless attachment",
      :body =>File.read(@file_name),
      :content => File.read(@file_name)

Comment: Which version of ActionMailer are you using, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
attachments[report[0].gsub(/.*\//,'')] = File.read(report[0])
```

Comment: now the attachment is shown in the body of the message not as a downloadable attachment

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
attachments[report[0].gsub(/.*\//,'')] = { 
  :mime_type => 'text/plain', 
  :content => File.read(report[0]),
  :content_disposition => 'attachment'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpfull.
And your test.txt file should be in public folder.

```
attachment "text/plain" do |a|
  a.filename = "test.txt" 
  a.body = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/public/test.txt")
end
```

and for a excel file

```
attachment "application/vnd-ms-excel" do |a|
  a.filename = "test.xls" 
  a.body = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/public/test.xls")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mail.attachments[report[0].split('/').last] = File.read(report[0])
```